# Latest gpg in a script with --passphrase-fd asking for passphrase in Docker container

Tags: linux, debian, encryption, gnupg, docker

I use `gpg` in Docker `Debian:latest` automatic build and the `gpg` in the terminal it works, but when I use in a script, no matter I do, ***it asks for the passphrase***, I do like this:

```
passphrase=$(cat /build/secure/passphrase.txt)
echo $passphrase | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --import /build/secure/gpg/secret-signing-key.pgp
```

but if I do in the terminal, it works!

Why? How come?

Comment: What's the output of `gpg --version` in both the container and on your host?

Comment: You can also directly use `--passphrase-file`, without setting the environment variable by reading from a file. Anyway, newer `echo` passphrases on multi-user machines: all other users will be able to read arguments for all other running applications, even if they're executed by another users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GnuPG 2, `gpg-agent` and Loopback Pinentry

GnuPG 2.0 and newer only consider `--passphrase-...`-options when `--batch` is also applied. From `man gpg`:

> Note that this passphrase is only used if the option `--batch`  has  also  been
>                 given.  This is different from GnuPG version 1.x.

So a working command for GnuPG 2.0 would be:

```
gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --import <path>
```

Furthermore, since GnuPG 2.1, `gpg-agent` handles all secret key operations and also asks for the passphrase. The idea behind this is to have a small core application handling the most critical bits of cryptography, and having the (comparably) large GnuPG with potentially more bugs and security issues application doing all the other stuff. By default, `gpg-agent` will not query `gpg` for the passphrase, but try to ask the user directly (which will obviously fail in an unattended build). There is a last escape, though: you can use `--pinentry-mode loopback` to make `gpg-agent` query `gpg` for the passphrase, but as this impacts security as discussed before, you must also configure `gpg-agent` to allow loopback pinentry.

Add following line to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
allow-loopback-pinentry
```

Now, you should be able to use following command in GnuPG 2.1 and newer:

```
gpg --batch --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-fd 0 --import <path>
```

### Passing in the `gpg-agent` Socket

A better option than importing private keys to Docker containers is usually to store (and unlock) the private key on the host, and then passing a `gpg-agent` socket into the Docker container. This way, the critical secrets never will enter the Docker container, and you can be very sure it will not be stored in the image layers and published by accident.